# Undetected Django app when installing from git

Tags: django, github

I'm having trouble installing `django-admin_action_mail` from git.

I tried to install it via:

```
pip install
git+https://github.com/mjbrownie/django-admin_action_mail.git
```

But Django did not pick it up when I added it to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What did you put in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I think the problem is that the egg contains the actual code

Comment: And with the app in INSTALLED_APPS, what happens when you start your server?

Comment: server runs but I dont see the app

Comment: do you know any other simple Django app for sending email to selected users?

Comment: If the server runs, the app installed fine - did you configure the email action in your admin.py? Add the URLs to your urls.py?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't "see the app"? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I'm getting urlconf error when trying to access admin_action_mail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin code for that app is commented out (see here: https://github.com/mjbrownie/django-admin_action_mail/blob/master/admin_action_mail/admin.py ) so nothing is going to show up on the admin page - even if it's working and enabled.

It looks as though you need to create your own models to handle the mailing functions. Take a look at the [README](https://github.com/mjbrownie/django-admin_action_mail/blob/master/README) where it tells you to add something like the following in your app's `admin.py`:

```
from admin_action_mail.actions import mail_action

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    #Note all args are optional
    actions = [
        mail_action(
            'description' : "Send Email to Related Users",
            'email_dot_path' : 'email', # dot path string to email field (eg 'user.email')
            'email_template_html' : 'admin_action_email/email.html'
            'reply_to' : 'noreply@example.com' # defaults to request.user.email
        )
    ]

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Have you added a model like that to your own app's `admin.py`?

EDIT: As the problem appears to be with installation, the following should help:

You can add arbitrary paths to your wsgi path spec, that means it will pick up Python app modules in other locations. Assuming your app is installed in `/home/user2161049/myapp` you can put your external modules under `/home/user2161049/myapp/external`. In this case copy the contents of that app into `/home/user2161049/myapp/external/admin_action_mail/`.

To add this to your `settings.py`:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'external'))
```

The first line defines `SITE_ROOT` based on the current running script (`setup.py`) at startup. The second adds the `external` folder into the search path. You can put anything you want in there, and even define a specific folder somewhere else if you want to keep your externals out of your app folder. Restart the server and it should find the app just fine.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the app was not installed properly.
Django could not pick it up.

Comment: It's weird for it not to error in that case. Did you restart the server after making the changes to `setup.py`?

Comment: what changes to setup.py?
I did couple of restarts to the server.

Comment: Adding it to the installed apps. Is it working now? You can always put the code where you like (I've always put external apps under a folder `/external` in the project folder) as long as it's in your Python/wsgi path.

Comment: no, its not on Python/wsgi path
how can i add it?
did you try to install this app?

Comment: 10x, it seems that Django did pick this app up but I had to copy the template folder to my project templates folder.

Comment: Again, that's a bit weird (it should find the template if the app is in the path and `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` is in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`), but glad you got it sorted!